# Writing to a text box from another thread/class

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am working with an old asp.net web application, and I am having a problem trying to write text to a bootstrap textbox from another thread. I have simplified the web app into the code shown below:

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using AspNet;

namespace ProblemApp
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.TextBox1.Text == "")
            {
                TextBox1.Text = "TEST";
            }
        }

        protected void UpdateButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AutoLogControl NewAutoLogger = new AutoLogControl();
            Thread AutoLoggerThread = new Thread(() => NewAutoLogger.StartAutoLogger(sender));
            AutoLoggerThread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Autolog.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ProblemApp
{
    public partial class AutoLogControl : _Default
    {
        public void StartAutoLogger(object sender)
        {
            //would normally listen for a condition to be met, but for
            //this example, just set the Textbox. This is where my issue
            //is. TextBox is null.
            TextBox1.Text = "TEST 2";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need to set the TextBox from StartAutoLogger(), but I get a null reference when I try. I have tried several other solutions, such as creating a public method within _Default to set the text, but this does not work either. Here are the supporting files if you need them.

Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProblemApp._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


    <div class="row panel-body verticle-align">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <h4><span class="label label-default"> Text Box : </span></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <asp:TextBox ID ="TextBox1" name="Textbox1" runat="server" Width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row btn-block panel-body">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateButton_Click" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
            <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton2" runat="server" OnClick="UpdateButton2_Click" Text="Update 2" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.designer.cs:

```
namespace ProblemApp {


public partial class _Default {

    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox TextBox1;

    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button UpdateButton;

    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button UpdateButton2;
}
}
```

Comment: can you change ID "TextBox" to something different and add Name Attribute with a better naming

Comment: Updated for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You may have your inheritance backwards. In `AutoLogControl` when you reference

```
TextBox1.Text = "TEST 2";
```

you're really calling:

```
AutoLogControl.TextBox1.Text = "TEST 2";
```

which is not a reference to the actual TextBox on your page:

```
_Default.TextBox1;
```

You are passing the `sender` object as a parameter, So you could:

1. Cast sender to it's appropriate type
2. get the associated page
3. search for the desired control (probably specify an additional parameter)

If you were to do this, `AutoLogClass` should not inherit from `_Default`, but possibly `System.Web.UI.UserControl` and should expose `StartAutoLogger` as a static method.

Alternately you can have _Default inherit from AutoLogControl and instead use :

```
Thread AutoLoggerThread = new Thread(() => this.StartAutoLogger(sender));
AutoLoggerThread.Start();
```

Though I do not know the context of the `AutoLogClass`, so that may not be suitable.

In either case, currently `AutoLogClass` *is a* `_Default` so instantiating it with `new` will create a *new* `_Default` page where the controls different from the original `_Default`. Referring to controls won't throw a compiler error because they do in fact exist in `AutoLogClass`'s parent, however they are not initialized, ergo: `null`.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation of my issue! Unfortunately though your solution does not work for me. If I set `AutoLogControl` to inherit from `System.Web.UI.UserControl`, and `_Default` to inherit from `AutoLogControl`, then use your suggestion of



`Thread AutoLoggerThread = new Thread(() => this.StartAutoLogger(sender));`



`AutoLoggerThread.Start();`

I get a compile error in `AutoLogger.cs` that states that `TextBox1` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @user7991682 you're right, if `_Default` inherits from `AutoLogControl`, `AutoLogControl` has no instance of `TextBox1`. Instead of using `TextBox1` explicitly, why not pass a parameter containing the target object? something like `this.StartAutoLogger(sender, target)`

Comment: @user7991682 perhaps make `StartAutoLogger` generic so you can include the type of `target`, then inside `StartAutoLogger` you can cast `target as T` (assuming you want to pass something other than a `TextBox`)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get that to work either. I'm relatively new to C#, so I might be missing something simple.